# How to show a grid view inside a grid view?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am developing a windows 8 app. And I want to display a `GridView` inside of another `GridView` item template. And I have added a visibility binding to the inner `GridView`, but the binding doesn't work when wrapping the `GridViewItems` in the outer `GridView`. It works when i use a simple `ListView` or `GridView` without any wrapping.

This is the main `GridView` with wrapping

```
<GridView 
    Name="feedGridView"
    Background="Transparent" 
    SelectionMode="None"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyFeedGridView}">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Height="600" Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

The style for "MyFeedGridView" which contains another `GridView`

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyFeedGridView">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="500">                
        <StackPanel x:Name="gridViewStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <GridView
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                x:Name="myFeedGridViewInListView"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyFeedGridViewInListView}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding listContent}"
                Height="100"
                Visibility="{Binding listContent,Converter={StaticResource FeedListToVisibilityConverter}}"
                SelectionMode="None"
                Width="400" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

I am using a converter to hide or show the inner `GridView`. The below is the converter that i am using

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
    List<ContentList> contents = value as List<ContentList>;

    return (contents != null && contents.Count > 0) ? Visibility.Visible :    Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

My problem is that the inner GridView gets hidden for all the items or gets visible for all the items irrespective of the listcontent that I have bound.

I have noticed is that this is happening only when I set the `ItemsPanel`. If I remove the `VariableSizedWrapGrid` property then it's working as expected. But I need to wrap the items after each column so I can't do away with it.

Please let me know if you have any clue why this is happening.

Thanks

EDIT:
Attaching image of how the grid view items should be arranged. If you see the first item of the grid view, it has another grid view inside the grid view item representing songs. So this inner grid view will be empty for some items and populated for some. So I had written a visibility converter to show and hide the inner grid view. And when am using the converter,if the first grid view item has inner grid view items(songs then it will show inner grid view for all the items and if the first grid view item doesnt have any inner grid view items(songs) then it hides inner grid view for all the main grid view items.

Let me know if its not clear. [image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you are trying to achieve and how your view model is built? Perhaps you could sketch the boxes of your `GridViewItems` and the direction and order you want them to wrap?

Comment: @FilipSkakun I have added an image. Let me know if its not clear.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a `GridView` is that it uses the same size for all its `GridViewItems` by default. You can use a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as its `ItemsPanel`, but that will disable virtualization and so you won't be able to use your `GridView` with a large number of items (more than a few dozen) without incurring performance cost.

For your scenario you could use a `GridView` with a non-uniform `ItemsSource` - one where some items represent the main list item and some that represent lists of songs and use the `ItemTemplateSelector` to specify which template to use for which type of item. It's not ideal of course, but this is what your easiest option is. One problem is that some of these song lists might end up orphaned in a different column than the item they are associated with, so for the ugly workaround you might need to figure out the number of items per column and in the list also include empty items or rearrange the items so that the empty-end-of-column items are filled with items that don't have any song lists associated with them.

A better option might be to use a `VariableSizedWrapGrid` as `ItemsSource` or simply use a manually populated `Grid` and add a `more...` item at the end that opens a `ListView`, since vertical lists IMHO are easier to scroll than horizontal `GridViews`. You would still need to use a non-uniform `ItemsSource` and `ItemTemplateSelector` to get the desired layout and keep virtualization of the list, but that's what you get.